# Document used by multiple people, i need it to automatically refresh to reflect new changes

Tags: refresh

So i have a document in excel that is open by 20 different people and gets updated hourly.

What people do is close the document and reopen it in sharepoint to see the new changes.

Is there anyway to have the document automatically refresh to reflect the new changes?

Comment: We use SharePoint 2019 and I have the same question. Unfortunately, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest upgrading to SharePoint 2013 when it is released or using Google Docs.